# Is this formula/problem hard to crack?

Tags: hash

I have a simple calculation. Its inputs should be very hard to discover, but I want to be certain, hence the question.

Start with value $A$, a known 1024-bit number.

Input $I_1$ and $I_2$ are 512-bit numbers, and their hashes are known as $h_1 =Hash(I_1),  h_2=Hash(I_2)$.

Output $O$ is the result of $O=(A\cdot I_1)+I_2$.

Given $A,O,h_1$, and $h_2$, is it feasible to brute force $I_1$ and $I_2$?

Comment: I've little formalized your question. What is the origin of this question? What are the assumptions of this hash function? Are there any modulus operation on the calculation of the output $O$?

Comment: Thnx, looks much better now indeed! The hash function can be any hash function really, lets assume SHA3. But even without the hashed values, is it possible to figure out I1 and I2. The hashed values are quite irrelevant but it assumes a single solution to the inputs.

Comment: And no modulus operations @kelalaka that formula is all there is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$O=(A\cdot I_1)+I_2$$

Take $\mod A$ of the equation.

$$O \bmod A=\left( ( A\cdot I_1)+I_2 \right) \bmod A = I_2 \bmod A$$

So we get the $I_2$. the rest is substructing the $I_2$

$$O - I_2 = A\cdot I_1$$ and the final is simply dividing by A.

$$I_1 = \frac{O - I_2}{A} $$

The given $h_1$ and $h_2$ are not used! One may argue to use the hashes to identify the multiple solutions, however, the [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) says they are unique since $A$ is a 1024-bit number and $I_i$'s are 512-bit numbers.

Comment: Thnx, now given this one A=15,i1=10, i2=100 (15*10)+100=250. Results in i1=16, i2=10. Which is -A- solution. But it won't match the hash of i1 and i2. Since there will be a limited amount of valid combinations. Given these numbers are 512 bit. How large would the 'search space' be? And how hard(if at all) wil it be to compute an equation that follows this 'line' of potential values Forgive if not using the right terms.

Comment: The $A$ must be bigger than $I$'s, that was your requirement. So. the division theorem?  In your example, $A < I_2$ and that is the reason for the failure.

Comment: What does that failure mean? The size of A is actually irrelevant for the formula itself. It is just how the random number work that are generated. I am wondering how big the search space for potential candidates for i1 and i2 is. As in how easy would it be to guess those value given that you know the hashes.

Comment: @ovanwijk in your question you said `Start value A is a known 1024-bit number.` and `Input I1 and I2 are 512-bit numbers`. If you were designed in a way that $A \ll I_i$ than it would make more than one solution. And taking a known modulus will make it more complicate though. Now those are another question.

Comment: Not sure if I follow. There already is more then 1 solution. I have no control over the input really. Just that the end result must not be over 2048 bit. Note that it is not a problem there are more solutions. The question is mainly how hard it is to find That hashed solution

Comment: @ovanwijk I've given an answer under the premise of your question and your example in the comment doesn't fit your question's premises that $A > I_s$, at least.

Comment: Thnx, this is exactly the precise insight I was looking for. The multiple solutions is only possible when A < Ix. Good enough for this question indeed. But any idea if A = 512 Bit and Ix is 768 but, how large the search space would be? Anyway, this info is already gold! Thnx

Comment: It seems that if I would do O=(A+i1)*i2 your method doesn't work, even with A > Ix. Or am I overlooking something here.

Comment: @ovanwijk it will not. Because that is $O = I_2 A + I_2 I_1$ so the remainder $I_2 I_1$ can be bigger than $A$.

Comment: Just to conclude in this case: doing  O=(A+i1)*i2 will -in essence- hide i1 & i2?

Comment: @ovanwijk It will still leak information. Like take $\bmod A$ then you will know the value of $I_1 I_2$ under the $\bmod A$, so $I_1 I_2 = a + k A$. The number of solutions really depends on the numbers. Also, one can go to try to factor $O$ since $I_i$ need not to be prime and $A + I_1$ can be a product of small numbers. One has to set the parameters to see the probability of those. This is a far into prime distribution, etc.

Comment: Currently, I am generating probably primes for all parameters. But with large primes at 512 bit (I can go higher but the computation complexity increases quite steeply). If it requires it's factorization then it would be 'as secure' as other solutions depending on the factorization problem no? I know I am making massive generalizations here.